# MVC Model Validation RegEx

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-5, model-validation

I need a regex to be able to validate a domain name without http:// or https://

What I mean:

Valid Should Be:

```
domain.com
domain.fr
domain.it
domain.whateverelse
subdomain.domain.com
subdomain.doamin.fr
subdomain.domain.whateverelse
```

Invalid Should Be:

```
domain
http://domain.com
https://domain.com
https://domain.whateverelse
http://subdomain.domain.com
http://subdomain.domain.fr
http://subdomain.domain.whateverelse
```

This is what I came so far:

```
(http(s)?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+[.com]+(/[/?%&=]*)?
```

For example the regex above considers domain.whatever as invalid ... so basically works just with .com

Comment: you mean this http://regex101.com/r/cJ9uZ9/1

Comment: @AvinashRaj: quite close but not exactly: that regex matches also `domain`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: `domain` should be invalid

Comment: but this will http://regex101.com/r/cJ9uZ9/5 work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one look realy good:

```
(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```

Is comming from: http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=96
Where can find a lot more ;)